# LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, linker

After compiling everything, I get those errors on Visual C++ Studio 2010.

Probably I am missing any library? If it's that can you help me to guess which one?Err

````
1>     Creating library \Bin\Engine.lib and object \Bin\Engine.exp
1>UILoginNew.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::thread::detach(void)" (?detach@thread@boost@@QAEXXZ)
1>UILoginNew.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __thiscall boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept(void)" (?start_thread_noexcept@thread@boost@@AAE_NXZ)
1>SMCSCAN.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>UILoginNew.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>NetClient.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>StdH.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>smcPars.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>UILoginNew.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base(void)" (??1thread_data_base@detail@boost@@UAE@XZ)
1>StdH.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>smcPars.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>SMCSCAN.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>\Bin\Engine.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========```
````

Comment: It sounds like if you call library functions but the linker is not able to find the lib file. You must to set the path of your lib file in Addditional Library Directories project property. And the lib name in Additional Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by reinstalling Boost 1.58. 32 bits
Maybe I had x64 libs